How to flush/reset the backlog of a python observer and PatternMatchingEventHandler when lots of changes happen in close succession?
I'm using a python PatternMatchingEventHandler watchdog to call a function each time a file is created (using self.on_created) within a watched directory tree. Minimal code example below. The function is slow, so if a lot of new files are created in a short time period, I can end up with a huge backlog and there are times when I want to fast-forward past them.  Since the observer/watchdog pair eventually processes all the files, I'm imagining that at some level, there is an internal list of files that were created, and a loop that calls on_created sequentially for each file in that list. I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to flush/delete the list of events? Or check the length of the backlog and if it gets too long, do an empty loop over them?
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
class foo(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(
            self,patterns = ['*.txt'],ignore_patterns = None,
            ignore_directories = False,case_sensitive = True,
        )
        self.function = bar # defined elsewhere. Takes about 1 sec per file
    def on_created(self,event):
        self.function(event.src_path)

from watchdog.observers import Observer
the_handler = foo()
the_observer = Observer()
the_observer.schedule(the_handler,path_to_dir,recursive=True)
the_observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01) 
except:
    the_observer.stop()
the_observer.join()
    


the_observer.event_queue.queue.clear() will remove all items in the queue but leave the observer and watchdog still running.
